# Calculate Percentage from count total with mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to make another array of sum (from count). And calculate the percentage next to it. So i wrote:

```
select vwr_cntry, COUNT(vwr_id) as count1 from viewer_log
where not vwr_cntry = ''
group by vwr_cntry

Union all

select 'SUM'
vwr_cntry, COUNT(count1)//cannot count the 'count1'

from viewer_log
order by count desc
limit 5
```

The idea is to list the top 5 country of visitors and calculate the percent of each country (vwr_cntry). I expect something like this:

```
+---------------+---------+-----+
|   Country     |count    |  %  |
+---------------+---------+-----+
|Thailand       |2314     |     |
+---------------+---------+-----+
|United States  |957      |     |
+---------------+---------+-----+
|Japan          |645      |     |
+---------------+---------+-----+
|United Kingdom |70       |     |
+---------------+---------+-----+
|China          |52       |     |
+---------------+---------+-----+
```

But it throw the error : **Unknown column 'count' in 'field list'**

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: did you miss a group by vwr_cntry in the second part?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it still have error. I think it cannot refer to the 'count1'

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    vwr_cntry,
    COUNT(*) AS cntry_cnt,
    100.0 * COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM viewer_log) AS pct
FROM viewer_log
GROUP BY vwr_cntry
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 5
```

This is just a simple `GROUP BY` query.  It uses a non correlated subquery to find the total row count, for use in computing the percentage.

Comment: Thanks but from manual calculation, the percent of visitor from Thailand should be 57%. But from your script is just only 0.01. It summed all of the rows not just from the cntry_cnt

Comment: @Wilf Sorry...I forgot to multiply by 100.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first get top 5 countries, e.g.:

```
SELECT vwr_cntry, COUNT(vwr_id) AS 'counts'
FROM viewer_log
GROUP BY vwr_cntry
ORDER BY COUNT(vwr_id) DESC LIMIT 5;
```

Then, wrap it into another query to calculate sum, e.h.:

```
SELECT a.vwr_cntry, a.counts, SUM(a.counts) as 'sums'
FROM (
  SELECT vwr_cntry, COUNT(vwr_id) AS 'counts'
  FROM viewer_log
  GROUP BY vwr_cntry
  ORDER BY COUNT(vwr_id) DESC LIMIT 5
) a;
```

And then, add the formula to calculate percentage, e.g.:

```
SELECT b.vwr_cntry, b.counts, b.sums, (b.counts/b.sums)*100 AS 'percentage'
FROM (
  SELECT a.vwr_cntry, a.counts, SUM(a.counts) as 'sums'
  FROM (
    SELECT vwr_cntry, COUNT(vwr_id) AS 'counts'
    FROM viewer_log
    GROUP BY vwr_cntry
    ORDER BY COUNT(vwr_id) DESC LIMIT 5
  ) a
) b;
```